# Installing OpenCV fails for missing header files

Tags: pi-2, opencv

I am trying to install `opencv 3.0.0` on my raspberry pi 2b but I keep running into erros... currently, it complains about the following missing header files when I run the following `cmake` command:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.0.0/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

```bsh
$ cat /home/pi/opencv-3.0.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log | grep fatal
/home/pi/opencv-3.0.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: sys/videoio.h: No such file or directory
/home/pi/opencv-3.0.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: ffmpeg/avformat.h: No such file or directory
```

They do exist in my raspberry pi:

```bsh
$ locate avformat.h
/home/pi/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/include/ffmpeg_/libavformat/avformat.h
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libavformat/avformat.h

$ locate videoio.h
/home/pi/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/include/opencv2/videoio.hpp
/home/pi/opencv-3.0.0/modules/videoio/include/opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp
/usr/include/sys/videoio.h
```

I tried to symlink them into `/usr/include` under their respective paths, but it didn't work...

Anything I am doing wrong?

**Note**
I am trying to follow [this guide](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/04/raspbian-stretch-install-opencv-3-python-on-your-raspberry-pi/) for the installation

**Edit**
OS release:

```bsh
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: What operating system, what version do you use? Raspberry Pi OS Buster?

Comment: @Ingo good question! yes, version `10 (buster)`. Added to original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you try to build OpenCV from source. If you do not need exactly `opencv 3.0.0` there is no need to hassle with building from source. With **Raspberry Pi OS Buster** you can just install `opencv 3.2.0` from its repository.

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install python3-opencv
```

should do it. Look with

```
rpi ~$ apt list *opencv*
```

whatever else is available for OpenCV.

Comment: if I could only upvote and accept more than once! thanks @Ingo ! I was working on this for about 2 weeks!

Comment: p.s. it installed `opencv 4.4` but this is actually better